# Query to join multiple record to one record with multiple column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have problem to make multiple record become one record with multiple column in oracle. This is my query:

```
SELECT cnim, ckddos FROM  tjadsidangast j, tsidangast s 
WHERE j.cnojadwal=s.cnojadwal AND cnim='1111500003'
```

the result:

```
+------------+--------+
|  CNIM      | CKDDOS |
+------------+--------+
| 1111500003 |  00105 |
| 1111500003 |  00060 |
| 1111500003 |  00126 |
+------------+--------+
```

i have try this query:

```
SELECT cnim,
   LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ckddos,','))
   KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS elements
FROM   (SELECT cnim,
           ckddos,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cnim ORDER BY cstatus) AS curr,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cnim ORDER BY cstatus) -1 AS prev
    FROM   tsidangast j, tjadsidangast s WHERE j.cnojadwal=s.cnojadwal AND 
cnim='1111500003')
GROUP BY cnim
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND cnim = PRIOR cnim
START WITH curr = 1;
```

the result is:

```
+------------+---------------------+
|     CNIM   |  ELEMENTS           |
+------------+---------------------+
| 1111500003 |  00126,00105,00060  |
+------------+---------------------+
```

my question is: how i can make the result become this output:

```
+------------+--------+-------+-------+
|     CNIM   |    MD  |  P1   |  P2   |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+
| 1111500003 |  00126 | 00105 | 00060 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of slow (and unneeded here) hierarchical query, use `pivot`:

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a1641/1)</sup>**

```
select * 
  from (select row_number() over (order by cstatus) rn, cnim, ckddos
          from your_join
          where cnim = '1111500003')
  pivot (max(ckddos) for rn in (1 md, 2 p1, 3 p2))
```

In case this is Oracle version 10 or below replace `pivot` with `max(case ...)`:

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a1641/2)</sup>**

```
select cnim, 
       max(case when rn = 1 then ckddos end) md, 
       max(case when rn = 2 then ckddos end) p1,
       max(case when rn = 3 then ckddos end) p2 
  from (
    select row_number() over (order by cstatus) rn, cnim, ckddos
      from your_join
      where cnim = '1111500003')
  group by cnim
```

This solution is similiar to @D-Shih's, but you should't hardcode `ckddos` values in query, because this is what you are looking for. 
What you should and can hardcode is row numbers (1, 2, 3).

Comment: so many thanks for your answer....
i try :
SELECT cnim, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ckddos END) md, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ckddos END) p1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ckddos END) p2 
  FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cstatus) rn, cnim, ckddos
      FROM tjadsidangast j, tsidangast s
      WHERE j.cnojadwal=s.cnojadwal AND cnim = '1111500003')
  GROUP BY cnim 

a little modification from your query...thanks a lot :)